# Can I answer someone's request with: "That, I can do."

Tags: grammar, that

A friend asks me to do a task, is it proper to reply "That, I can do" in speaking form? or Should I still say "I can do that" ? 
To provide more background, a friend asked me to do "A" task, but I did not want to do that, then he asked me to do "B" task, then I reply: "That I can do".... Is it proper?

Comment: Omit the comma.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks, which means it is actually ok to reply "That I can do", am I right? I have this question because my friend said that is not proper and I should not reply that way.... Thus, I am wondering.

Comment: Yes. This is an example of the construction called Topicalization or Y-Movement. It moves the object to the beginning of  a sentence, instead of the end, to emphasize it. The topicalized word is often strongly stressed.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you, Thank you so much for your information :)

Comment: @JohnLawler If you know the answer, write an answer.

Comment: @Adam John Lawler is a linguist held in high regard; be grateful for his contributions and learn from them.

Answer (score 2):

*That, I can do* is not nearly as common as *I can do that*. [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=That%20I%20can%20do%2C%20I%20can%20do%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThat%20I%20can%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20can%20do%20that%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CThat%20I%20can%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20can%20do%20that%3B%2Cc0) shows how much less common it is, at least in printed form.

[image: I can do that]

Having said that, it *is* grammatical, and it might be used in the context of certain dialogue. You also don't need to remove the comma (as was mentioned in a comment under the question). In the right kind of dialogue, a pause might be natural and a comma warranted:

> "I can't do that."
>   "What about this?"
>   "*That*, I can do."

Speaking personally, I'd be more likely to use that expression in that particular exchange than I would *I can do that*. The reason is that the emphasis is more obviously placed on *that* if it's the first word in the sentence.

However, as a general statement, and in more contexts than not, the simple *I can do that* would probably be more common.

Comment: Yep. Completely agree about the comma and emphasis in that context.